# Eclipse importing android project, error in xml, but works in java code

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to import this android project in eclipse.

https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView

In xml, when I'm trying to use the ImageView

```
<com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12sp"
        app:border="true"
        app:border_color="#EEEEEE"
        app:border_width="4dp"
        app:shadow="true" />
```

I'm getting error

> error: Error parsing XML: unbound   prefix

But I'm able to use the CircularImageView in Java code. When I type in Circular, suggestion opens as ..... com.pkmmte.circularimageview

Then why is it not working in xml? Please help..

Edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/ListB" >

    <!--
         <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgvProfilePic"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12sp" />
    -->

    <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12sp"
        app:border="true"
        app:border_color="#EEEEEE"
        app:border_width="4dp"
        app:shadow="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblFamilyMemberItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgvProfilePic"
        android:text="Name: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/DarkGray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblFamilyMemberRelationItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/lblFamilyMemberItem"
        android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgvProfilePic"
        android:text="Relation: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/DarkGray" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_sprtr_line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height=".5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgvProfilePic"
        android:background="#D3D3D3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit:

I was using a normal ImageView before and the below code was working. Now I've replaced it with CircularImageView, it causing app to crash at run time

```
public class FamilyMemberListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Map<String, String>> {

    public static final String TAG = "FamilyMemberListAdapter";

    List<Map<String, String>> familyMemberList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    private Activity activity;

    public FamilyMemberListAdapter(Activity activity,
            List<Map<String, String>> familyMemberList) {
        super(activity, R.layout.activity_gch_family_members, familyMemberList);
        this.activity = activity;
        this.familyMemberList = familyMemberList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.activity_gch_family_member_item, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.lblFamilyMemberName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblFamilyMemberItem);
            holder.lblFamilyMemberRelation = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblFamilyMemberRelationItem);
            holder.imgProfilePic = (CircularImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgvProfilePic);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        int accountId = Integer.valueOf(familyMemberList.get(position).get(
                "accountId"));
        holder.imgProfilePic.setTag(accountId);
        holder.lblFamilyMemberName.setText("Name: "
                + familyMemberList.get(position).get("name"));
        holder.lblFamilyMemberRelation.setText("Relation: "
                + familyMemberList.get(position).get("relation"));
        if (holder.imgProfilePic != null) {
            downloadProfilePicToImageView(holder.imgProfilePic, accountId);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return familyMemberList.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView lblFamilyMemberName;
        TextView lblFamilyMemberRelation;
        CircularImageView imgProfilePic;
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106): Process: com.bodimetrics, PID: 18106
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at com.viatom.azur.tools.FamilyMemberListAdapter.getView(FamilyMemberListAdapter.java:45)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1280)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1188)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:446)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.onMeasure(CustomViewAbove.java:456)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2112)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1228)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1464)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1119)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6060)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    ... 42 more
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.bodimetrics-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.bodimetrics-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
04-30 21:00:45.246: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInfl
```

Comment: Let's see your full layout. Specially the part where the namespace `app` is declared.

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: The `app` namespace is **never declared** in your RelativeLayout. Something like `xmlns:app="..."`

Comment: thank you adding app namespace removed the error. But now i getting run time error. Error inflating class com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView. Also when I switch to graphical layout I can't see the CircularImageView and there it says a warning "You must supply a layout_height attribute. but i've added height to all the elements in xml

Comment: Did you add the required import?

Comment: yes I did add xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto". Please see my new edit

Comment: yes I did add import.. import com.pkmmte.circularimageview.CircularImageView;

Comment: You must add the import into the Fragment Class as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110723/discussion-between-heisenberg-and-bob-malooga).